# Calling a python function in logstash

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash to parse some files into elasticsearch. I would like to call a python function passing to it some arguments from logstash and then to add the value returned by the function in a new field in elasticsearch. Is there a possibility to do that?

Otherwise I would be happy if there are any other suggestions to realize my use case which is as follows: While parsing an input file with logstash's grok filter into elasticsearch, I would like to count the number of documents of the same index in elasticsearch whose field "x" value matches that of the document being parsed (the current line in the input file), divide that by the total number of documents in that index and return the result to elasticsearch. I'm asking about python only because I know how to implement this algorithm wiht python.

Comment: "and return that value to elasticsearch", not add it as a field to the event you are parsing? Logstash is really meant to parse. Complex calculations based on data across events are better done once the data is in elasticsearch by interacting with elasticsearch directly, which is something you can definitely do with python

Comment: Yes what I need is to add the returned value from the python function as a field to the event I'm parsing. However, I don't want to parse the whole data first and then run the script once since as I said I'm getting the count of the documents and this is changing while I'm parsing the data (since a new document is added with each parsed line), and I'm interested exactly in this change.